# Written a webscraping script with help of selenium and python but do not get any output from my print?

Tags: python, selenium, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have tried to write some code by using selenium and python to webscrape a food shop. However I have hard time to get a good output from my code. The code below shows what I have done so far and the pictures shows the output. It feels like this should be easy but I do not really understand why I do not get any output.....

CODE

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver as wb
import pandas as pd
import time


#Initilise
driver = wb.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.coop.se/butiker-erbjudanden/coop/coop-ladugardsangen-/')

print(driver.current_url)
print(driver.title)


products= driver.find_elements_by_class_name("Grid-cell u-size1of2 u-xsm-size1of2 u-md-size1of4 u-lg- 
size1of6 js-drOffer js-offerItem")
for product in products:
  header = product.find_elements_by_class_name("ItemTeaser-heading")
  print(header.text)
```

[output of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QUr2.png)

Comment: find_elements returns an array of webelements.  Then you try to execute .text method on it. (header.text... did you want to iterate there?)

Answer (score 0):

To get list of product items header use following `css selector`.

Induce `allItemheader()` and wait for `presence_of_all_elements_located`()

```
allItemheader=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".ItemTeaser h3.ItemTeaser-heading")))
for header in allItemheader:
     print("Item Header: " + header.get_attribute("innerHTML"))
```

You need to import below libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

---

**Console output:**

```
Item Header: Färska miniburgare
Item Header: Kaffe/Ekologiskt kaffe
Item Header: Krögarpytt
Item Header: Vaniljyoghurt
Item Header: Läsk
Item Header: Juice
Item Header: Smör
Item Header: Kycklingbröstfilé
Item Header: Fikabröd
Item Header: Färska miniburgare
Item Header: Soppa/Ekologisk soppa
Item Header: Rismellis
Item Header: Julstjärna
Item Header: Morötter i påse
Item Header: Sill i glas
Item Header: Amaryllis
Item Header: Vaniljyoghurt
Item Header: Kycklingfärs
Item Header: Smörgåspålägg
Item Header: Läsk
Item Header: Mjuk kaka
Item Header: Juice
Item Header: Ekologisk Fetaost
Item Header: Gurka
Item Header: Lindösalami Chili
Item Header: Smör
Item Header: Wienerkorv/Varmkorv med skinn
Item Header: Gräddost
Item Header: Ekologisk Tofu
Item Header: Julrevbensspjäll
Item Header: Lammytterfilé
Item Header: Plommontomater i ask
Item Header: Satsumas
Item Header: Champinjoner i ask
Item Header: Amerikanska Pannkakakor
Item Header: Benfri fläskkotlett
Item Header: Stekfläsk
Item Header: Ekologisk alkoholfri glögg
Item Header: Färskost
Item Header: Öl 3,5 %
Item Header: Röd grapefrukt
Item Header: Fläckborttagning
Item Header: Babyvåtservetter 64-pack
Item Header: Ekologiska kokosflingor
Item Header: Kaffe/Ekologiskt kaffe
Item Header: Müsli
Item Header: Ekologiska majssnacks
Item Header: Frukt-/bärrullar
Item Header: Cashew Havssalt
Item Header: Ljusstake Bea
Item Header: Julservetter
Item Header: Fiskpinnar 30-pack
Item Header: Julmugg
```